# default navbar not getting displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navbar

"Custom.css"

```
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets"; 
    @import "bootstrap";
```

"application.html.erb"

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>AlphaBlog</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

       <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>

      <% render 'layouts/navigation' %>
      <% render 'layouts/messages' %>

      <%= yield %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

"_navigation.html.erb"

```
    nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
           </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

"application.js"

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxR2L.png)

cant get the navbar on display ...  I don't get any error on anything. Tried running the code without the _navigation partial...it seems to work as it gives an error missing template.   After adding the _navigation.html.erb it stops showing the error and loads the page without navbar. Have checked all the versions are fine required inclusions seems to be in order  Still cant get the navbar displayed

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the images with code.

Comment: thanks for the tip @jvillian, please help me now on this ....

Comment: Have you tried: `<%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>` (using `=` after `<%`)?

Comment: thanks a ton ... when everything is right .. its the silliest mistakes which get you ... i guess... thanks once again

Comment: Sure thing. I added as an answer with some comments for future searchers. Please feel free to vote/accept if you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is:

```
<% render 'layouts/navigation' %>
<% render 'layouts/messages' %>
```

Which should probably be:

```
<%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
```

The `=` adds the result of `render 'layouts/navigation'` to the document. Without it, you are rendering `layouts/navigation`, but the result is not added to the document.